Validate Object.assign shortcut in constructor
Is there a way to shorten constructor assignment in TypeScript?
The code below doesn't work, complains fields a and b are not initialised.
class Some {
  a: string; b: string

  constructor(props: { a: string, b: string }) {
    // Too verbose, especially for many props
    // this.a = props.a; this.b = props.b 
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }
}


If you're doing this just once, then anything will be clunky and verbose. If you are doing it multiple times, you can make a factory function to produce an "assign ctor" and then use it, as shown in the answer to the question this duplicates above.

Object.assign(this, props) is one of the more standard ways to do this. To get away from typescript errors, please use the non null assertion operator - ! for the properties you plan on assigning in the constructor:
class Some {
  a!: string; b!: string

  constructor(props: { a: string, b: string }) {
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }
}


For some reasons I don't like TS constructor syntax so I would go either with declare:
class Some {
  declare a: string; 
  declare b: string

  constructor(props: { a: string, b: string }) {
    // Too verbose, especially for many props
    // this.a = props.a; this.b = props.b 
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }
}

or a non nullish assertion (didn't use it though, maybe there're some complications):
class Some {
  a!: string; 
  b!: string

  constructor(props: { a: string, b: string }) {
    // Too verbose, especially for many props
    // this.a = props.a; this.b = props.b 
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }
}

